# Micronaut-Kafka with auto.commit.enable=false: how commit manually an offset

Tags: apache-kafka, micronaut, micronaut-kafka

I want to commit a message only if it was saved succesfully in database.

I understand I have turned off auto-commit with this application.yml

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: demoGrpcKafka
  executors:
    consumer:
      type: fixed
      nThreads: 1
#kafka.bootstrap.servers: localhost:9092
kafka:
  bootstrap:
    servers: localhost:9092
  consumers:
    default:
      auto:
        commit:
          enable: false
  producers:
    #default:
    demo-producer:
      retries: 2
```

Consumer

```
package com.tolearn.consumer

import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.annotation.KafkaKey
import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener
import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.annotation.Topic

@KafkaListener(groupId="myGroup")
class DemoConsumer {
    @Topic("testkey")
    fun receive(@KafkaKey key: String?,
                msg: String,
                offset: Long,
                partition: Int,
                topic: String,
                timestamp: Long
    ){
        println("Key = $key " +
                "msg = $msg " +
                "offset = $offset " +
                "partition = $partition " +
                "topic = $topic " +
                "timestamp = $timestamp ")

        //saved to database
        
        // THE ISSUE IS HERE: how commit like consumer.commitOffsets(true) ?????
    }
}
```

In other words, how I either commitOffset or commitSync() or any other alternative to commit the message manually while using Micronaut-Kafka?

*** second edition

I returned to application.yaml

```
  consumers:
    default:
      auto:
        commit:
          enable: false
```

*** third edit

I tried add either io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.Acknowledgement (deprecated) or import io.micronaut.messaging.Acknowledgement and either one caused

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'name': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
```

It seems I have to do something else in order to Micronaut inject such Acknowledgement object. What I am missing bellow?

```
package com.tolearn.consumer

import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.Acknowledgement
import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.annotation.KafkaKey
import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener
import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.annotation.OffsetStrategy
import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.annotation.Topic
//import io.micronaut.messaging.Acknowledgement
//import io.micronaut.messaging.annotation.Header

@KafkaListener(
        groupId="myGroup",
        offsetStrategy=OffsetStrategy.SYNC_PER_RECORD
)
class DemoConsumer {
    @Topic("demotopic")
    fun receive(@KafkaKey key: String?,
                acknowledgement: Acknowledgement,
                msg: String,
                offset: Long,
                partition: Int,
                topic: String,
                timestamp: Long
                //,header: Header
    ){
        println("Key = $key " +
                "msg = $msg " +
                "offset = $offset " +
                "partition = $partition " +
                "topic = $topic " +
                "timestamp = $timestamp "
                // + "header = $header"
        )

        //saved to database

        // how commit like consumer.commitOffsets(true)
        //Consumer.commitSync()

        acknowledgement.ack();
    }
}
```

The whole log is

```
18:13:13.812 [consumer-executor-thread-1] ERROR i.m.c.k.e.KafkaListenerExceptionHandler - Kafka consumer [com.tolearn.consumer.DemoConsumer@17e970dd] failed to deserialize value: Error deserializing key/value for partition demotopic-0 at offset 4. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition demotopic-0 at offset 4. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: io.micronaut.core.serialize.exceptions.SerializationException: Error deserializing object from JSON: Unrecognized token 'name': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (byte[])"name: "Hello"
"; line: 1, column: 6]
    at io.micronaut.jackson.serialize.JacksonObjectSerializer.deserialize(JacksonObjectSerializer.java:73)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.serde.JsonSerde.deserialize(JsonSerde.java:82)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:60)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:1365)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$3400(Fetcher.java:130)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1596)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.access$1700(Fetcher.java:1432)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:635)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1308)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1237)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1210)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.processor.KafkaConsumerProcessor.lambda$process$8(KafkaConsumerProcessor.java:396)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'name': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (byte[])"name: "Hello"
"; line: 1, column: 6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1851)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:717)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3588)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3564)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._matchToken2(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2899)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._matchNull(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2870)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:844)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:757)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4664)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4513)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3529)
    at io.micronaut.jackson.serialize.JacksonObjectSerializer.deserialize(JacksonObjectSerializer.java:71)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
18:13:13.812 [consumer-executor-thread-1] INFO  o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - [Consumer clientId=demo-grpc-kafka-demo-consumer, groupId=myGroup] Seeking to offset 5 for partition demotopic-0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-kafka/latest/api/io/micronaut/configuration/kafka/annotation/KafkaListener.html) you can set the `offsetStrategy` in your `KafkaListener` annotation like

```
@KafkaListener(groupId="myGroup", offsetStrategy=OffsetStrategy.SYNC)
class DemoConsumer {
    @Topic("testkey")
    fun receive(@KafkaKey key: String?,
[...]
```

to one of the following options:

```
ASYNC: Asynchronously commit offsets using Consumer.commitAsync() after each batch of messages is processed.
ASYNC_PER_RECORD: Asynchronously commit offsets using Consumer.commitSync() after each ConsumerRecord is consumed.
AUTO: Automatically commit offsets with the Consumer.poll(long) loop.
DISABLED: Do not commit offsets.
SYNC: Synchronously commit offsets using Consumer.commitSync() after each batch of messages is processed.
SYNC_PER_RECORD: Synchronously commit offsets using Consumer.commitSync() after each ConsumerRecord is consumed.
```

If I understand your question correctly, you want to set it to `SYNC`.

Comment: thanks, you undertood correctly my question. What is Consumer from Consumer.commitSync()? IntelliJ suggested org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer but it miss commitSync. Can your provide a snipeet code?

Comment: I understand the documentation that you do not need to specifically call consumer.commitSync() yourself, but that this is happening behind the scenes when using the offsetStrategy option within your KafkaListener as shown in my answer.

Comment: you still need to disable the auto commit within your application.yaml file.

Comment: Well it is prety the same to say "YOU CAN'T DO MANUALLY'. I want in case of failing to save to database avoid commit for while and after while, if still failing to save, I will resend to Death Letter Queue and then commit. Are you sure it isn't possible to hold commit?

Comment: Few minutes ago there was an answer here pointing to https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-kafka/latest/guide/index.html#kafkaOffsets. I am checking this guide. Suddenly the answer dissapered.

Comment: I guess this answer was a link only answer which the community reviewd to be removed

Comment: I followed carefulled the documentation by adding "acknowledgement: Acknowledgement" and now I am getting "com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException". Do I have to do something else in order to inject Acknowledgement object? Kindly see above whole log and consumer code

Comment: My bad. I fixed by change the position of Acknowledgement parameter to end, after msg parameter.